# C# TimeSpan two days equal the same time span?

Tags: asp.net, datetime, c#-4.0, timespan

So I have a situation where I need to trigger certain events on a specific day, I thought I would use TimeSpan to get that specific day, the idea here is when the TimeSpan.Days == 0 I trigger my event, if its Less then or Greater then 0 do nothing...
but I thought this would work but two days give me 0
Here is what I am doing.

```
TimeSpan timeSpanDays = DateTime.Parse("12/13/2011").Subtract(DateTime.Now.AddDays(76));
TimeSpan timeSpanDays1 = DateTime.Parse("12/14/2011").Subtract(DateTime.Now.AddDays(76));

TimeSpan timeSpanMonths = DateTime.Parse("2011-11-28").Subtract(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2));
TimeSpan timeSpanMonths1 = DateTime.Parse("2011-11-29").Subtract(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2));

Console.WriteLine("14 days after issuance: {0}",timeSpanDays.Days);
Console.WriteLine("14 days after issuance: {0}",timeSpanDays1.Days);
Console.WriteLine("\r\n");
Console.WriteLine("22 months after issuance: {0}",timeSpanMonths.Days);
Console.WriteLine("22 months after issuance: {0}",timeSpanMonths1.Days);
Console.WriteLine("\r\n");
Console.WriteLine("TESTING DATE {0}",DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2));
```

Here Are the results

> 14 days after issuance: 0
>
> 14 days after issuance: 0
>
> 22 months after issuance: 0
>
> 22 months after issuance: 0
>
> TESTING DATE 11/28/2011 10:55:43 AM

Is this because I'm not stripping the time on the DateTime.Now??
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!!!

Comment: LOL... tired... Changed it to Today instead of Now it was the time.

early morning fail

Answer (score 2):

You're misunderstanding what the `Days` property is I think.  I think what you want is `TotalDays`.

Comment: Agreed I did miss-understand the Days property, until my brain started to work :P and then changed my DateTime.Now to DateTime.Today, long story short I use Days which returns a integer, TotalDays returns whole and fractional days ie (1 or 0.418441473829861), I just needed the whole number so when it Equals 0 I trigger events, thanks for all the replys everyone!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have the total of day between two DateTime you need to use the [TotalDays](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan.totaldays.aspx) of TimeSpan.

TotalDays, TotalMinutes, TotalHours, TotalMilliseconds give you the total amount of time between the time span.

On the other hand, Days, Minutes, Hours and Milliseconds give you the current component of the instance.

So, you need to change you example to use Total methods.

```
TimeSpan timeSpanDays = DateTime.Parse("12/13/2011").Subtract(DateTime.Now.AddDays(76));
TimeSpan timeSpanDays1 = DateTime.Parse("12/14/2011").Subtract(DateTime.Now.AddDays(76));

TimeSpan timeSpanMonths = DateTime.Parse("2011-11-28").Subtract(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2));
TimeSpan timeSpanMonths1 = DateTime.Parse("2011-11-29").Subtract(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2));

Console.WriteLine("14 days after issuance: {0}",timeSpanDays.TotalDays);
Console.WriteLine("14 days after issuance: {0}",timeSpanDays1.TotalDays);
Console.WriteLine("\r\n");
Console.WriteLine("22 months after issuance: {0}",timeSpanMonths.TotalDays);
Console.WriteLine("22 months after issuance: {0}",timeSpanMonths1.TotalDays);
Console.WriteLine("\r\n");
Console.WriteLine("TESTING DATE {0}",DateTime.Now.AddMonths(2));
```

Comment: Why you do not trigger when it's under 0... i do not understand your comment above. TotalDays can be a fraction if it's less than 24 hours. If you need to do something special if it's not 1 day, just do a IF statement?

Comment: bool isValid = false;            
        TimeSpan timeSpan = dateTime.Subtract(executionDate.Date.AddDays(numberOfDays));
        if (timeSpan.Days == 0)
        {
            isValid = true;
        }
        return isValid;
This is in a helper method, this is a scheduled process i run daily, so if its anything but 0 return false.

So Days is what I need, not total days, I suppose i could use totalDays but I don't need the fractional days.